# How does the randint work in python for rsa use?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello can someone explain me why i get a error when I'm trying to use the gcd function...

this is my code:

```
import random
n1 = 544
r = random.randint(2,100)
while True:
    if gcd(r,n1) == 1:
        break
    else:
        r+=1
e = r
print e
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/oooo.py", line 8, in <module>
   if gcd(r, n1) == 1:
NameError: name 'gcd' is not defined
```

Comment: random.randint is better

Comment: you want `random.randint()` or `from random import randint` as your import

Comment: thanks a lot! however the error is now going to gcd. @MooingRawr

Comment: If you want to use the `gcd` function then you should import it. Or implement it yourself, it's pretty easy to write. In Python 2, there's a `gcd` in `fractions`.

Comment: @PM2Ring can you explain what you mean? I'm a fearly new with programming

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use gcd function from a library:

```
import random
from fractions import gcd
n1 = 544
r = random.randint(2,100)
while True:
    if gcd(r,n1) == 1:
        break
    else:
        r+=1
e = r
print e
```

And it will work.